# Binding an Image in WPF doesn't autoupdate on UI

Tags: c#, wpf, image, caching, mvvm

I'm currently stuck trying to display an Image on UI and autoupdate this whenever this Image changes. This is what I have so far

```
public abstract class Animals: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _image;
        public string Image
        {
            get { return _image; }
            set
            {
                if (_image != value)
                {
                    _image= value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And I'm using this function to be able to replace an Image being used by my application, that's the whole purpose of this, being able to show the new image on UI.

```
    public class UriToCachedImageConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
                    {
                        var image = new BitmapImage();

                        using (var stream = new FileStream(value.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            image.BeginInit();
                            image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                            image.StreamSource = stream;
                            image.EndInit();
                        }
                        return image;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return null;
            }
...
```

And here's is how I use it on XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <utils:UriToCachedImageConverter x:Key="uriToImageConv"></utils:UriToCachedImageConverter>
</Window.Resources>

<DataTemplate>
    <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource uriToImageConv}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

If I create a new instance of Animals with the updated Image, it does show the new Image on UI, while another already created Animals instance looking at the same Image path is showing the old one.

EDIT: Databinding actually works, because if I change Image to another Image path, it does update it on UI, the problem is updating an already loaded Image that got replaced or even deleted.

Comment: You have a `catch (Exception){return null;}` in there. This is a deadly sin of Exception handling and propably where you swallow the debugging information that you need. Please read up on the proper ways to do Exception handling. If you have code like that in your Example, I can not even guess what else goes wrong in your programm. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: Aside from that glarign issue in your Converter code, two minor things about the "Image" property: 1. It should propably be called ImagePath. It is not a image after all, but a path to a Image. 2. You should let the compiler write the property Name there. Asuming you are not running on a extremely outdate C# Version (pre 4.5), consider the CallerMemberName atribute: https://grenangen.se/node/75 It was practically added for this case.

Comment: Have you tried ignoring your image cache during creation in your converter? `image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;`

Comment: As a rule of thumb. Don't put any try catch blocks in at all. Use a set of generic error handlers instead.

Comment: @Tronald Yes, I tried it nevertheless it didn't work

Comment: Is animals in a separate library to the viewmodel you're using?

Comment: @Andy If by library you mean folder, yes. Animals is at a folder called Model and viewmodel is at a folder named ViewModel

Comment: No, I mean a separate dll.  You can find a viewmodel inheriting from a base viewmodel has to itself explicitly state it's implementing inpc before the view realises it is doing so. Easy to try that anyhow I suppose.

Comment: When the path to the image file, i.e. the value of the Image property does not actually change, the Binding ignores the property change notification. Get around this limitation by moving the converter code to your view model, i.e. declare a property of type `ImageSource`. Besides that, the whole converter is redundant anyway, because there is built-in automatic type conversion from string to ImageSource.

Comment: @Clemens Above works when I click a button or something that changes the ImageSource, but I foresee that what I asked is not what I want, because I would like this dynamically, aka when the image file I'm looking for get replaced, would like to update it on UI automatically, without pressing a button nor anything like that.

Comment: Then there should be something like a FileSystemWatcher that assigns a new value to a property of type ImageSource whenever the file changes.

Comment: Just used FileSystemWatcher and got it working, since what you said worked, feel free to post it as an answer I will be accept it!